# Index of vector of strings in c++

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a vector of string including :- chemistry physics maths.
I want to access first character of each word ie c of chemistry p of physics and m of maths. How to do that?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I have no clue how to do this

Comment: You just need to make a 2D vector , but i would recommend at least showing us some code even if it is wrong so we get more idea on how to tackle the question.

Comment: You need to write a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can output the first index element through this process.

I have made a 2D vector and applied a for loop so each row of the vector's first element is printed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec = {"chemistry", "maths", "physics"};

    for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
    {

         std::cout << vec[i][0];
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can also use a range based for loop

```
for (auto &i : vec)
    std::cout << i[0] << " ";
```

The output will be

```
c m p
```

Answer (score 1):

You can treat it like a 2D matrix of characters.

Given the vector of strings:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec = {"chemestry", "physics", "math"};
```

You can use a normal loop to access all first characters:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    std::cout << vec[i][0] << " ";
```

Or a range based loop:

```
for (auto &str : vec)
    std::cout << str[0] << " ";
```

Output:

```
c p m
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code should do the trick. If not then the Compiler is being a racist and doesn't like you that much. In that case you can just go-to your old buddy cpp.sh :D

String is a char Array and you can access it's contents from indexes like so

```
std::string str = "Hello";
std::cout << "First Index: " << str[0];
```

**Output:-**

```
H
```

Same goes for the vector as well

```
std::vector <char> str = "World!";
std::cout << "First Index: " << str[0];
```

**Output:-**

```
W
```

Now if you combine those two, it makes it a 2D Array so you have to access it like you access data from a 2D Array/Matrix.

```
std::vector <std::string> str = {"Hello", "World", "!"};
std::cout << "First Index Of Element 1: " << str[0][0] << std::endl
          << "First Index Of Element 2: " << str[1][0] << std::endl
          << "First Index Of Element 3: " << str[2][0] << std::endl;
```

**Output:-**

```
H
W
!
```

---

**Program:-**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector <std::string> vec = {"chemistry", "physics", "math"};
    for (int i=0; i < vec.size(); i++) {  //-- size(); Function gives the size of a vector
         std::cout << vec[i][0] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:-**

```
c
p
m
Press any key to continue...
```